# Meta-analysis of a bounded parameter

Tags: bayesian, correlation, meta-analysis, boundary

I am trying to conduct a meta-analysis of a bounded parameter, say, a correlation parameter $\rho \in [0, 1]$. I have multiple studies $i = 1, \dots, N$, each producing a likelihood $L_i(\rho_i), \rho_i \in [0, 1]$. And each study are with different sample size, therefore different precision of the $\rho_i$ estimates (which is probably already reflected in the flatness of the likelihood curve $L_i (\rho_i)$.

This parameter $\rho_i$ is likely close to 1 based on prior knowledge, therefore the normal asymptotics are not so valid because of the bounded parameter space.

The main interests are:

1. Assessing the heterogeneity of $\rho_i$ across studies.
2. Produce a single summary of $\rho$.
3. Test $H_0: \rho_i = 1, i \in 1, \dots, N$ accounting for different precision of $\rho_i$.

Is there any reference for guiding the analysis of such problems?

And if one is willing to further assume $\rho_i \in \text{Uniform}[0, 1]$, is there some established procedure to perform a Bayesian meta-analysis on the posterior distribution $\pi_i(\rho_i), i=1, \dots, N$?

Comment: Have you thought about transforming your parameter into an unbounded region (e.g. using inverse sigmoid or similar)?

Comment: I have a not-quite-finished paper that addresses all the issues you raise. I'm working on an answer that provides an introduction and summary. Do you mind telling me what the subject matter is?

Comment: @J.Delaney This seems plausible by transforming the parameter to unbounded space, and rely on normal assumption to meta-analyze mean + se. But the statistical properties are not so clear so i am searching for a more principled solution.

Comment: @mef that sounds very interesting. The subject matter is on meta-analyzing genetic correlation, e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5005434/ essentially each study corresponds to a correlation of genetic effects of a particular trait, and one would like to meta-analyze across traits. I believe surely other fields will have similar problems and i look forward to your answer.

Comment: Excellent! Can you describe the functional forms of the likelihoods? They don't need to be restricted to the unit interval; the prior will take care of that.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean specificly on the functional form of the likelihoods. A simplified description is $L(\sigma^2, \rho) = \text{MVN}(\text{data}; 0, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2 & \rho \sigma^2 \\ \rho \sigma^2 & \sigma^2 \end{bmatrix})$. And one can optimize jointly over $\sigma^2, \rho$ and describe the likelihood of $\rho$ ($\sigma^2$ as a nuiance parameter). And therefore, we can obtain the likelihood $L(\rho)$ for every $\rho \in [0, 1]$

Comment: That's exactly what I want! (Sorry I didn't see your response until just now.) Mathematica can integrate out $\sigma^2$ (using an inverse gamma prior or an improper prior proportional to 1 or $1/\sigma^2$) producing the likelihood for $\rho$. That's great. But the likelihood has a value of zero at $\rho = 1$ (unless the two variables in the data are exactly collinear, in which case the likelihood is infinite there). This behavior of the likelihood will cause difficulties in evaluating the hypothesis $\rho_i = 1$. Your interests 1 and 2 can still be addressed.

Comment: If these are correlations why not use the hyperbolic arctangent transformation (Fisher's z)? That is what most meta-analysts do.

Comment: Are the $\sigma^2$ variables known? Sometimes the standard error is assumed to be known in a meta-analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, your likelihood makes assessing the probability of $\rho_i = 1$ difficult if not impossible. I present a framework that addresses the other two main interests.

One way to think about the overall problem is as *latent-variable density estimation*. The summary would then be the "predictive" distribution for $\rho_{N+1}$. (I put "predictive" in quotes since the term is typically applied to observables.)

If you observed $\rho_{1:N} = (\rho_1, \ldots, \rho_N)$ then you could apply Bayesian density estimation directly and compute the predictive distribution:
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_{N+1}|\rho_{1:N}) = \int p(\rho_{N+1}|\theta)\,p(\theta|\rho_{1:N})\,d\theta ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|\rho_{1:N}) = \frac{p(\rho_{1:N}|\theta)\,p(\theta)}{p(\rho_{1:N})}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_{1:N}|\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^N p(\rho_i|\theta) . 
\end{equation}
The main choices are the form of $p(\rho_i|\theta)$ and the prior for $\theta$. [I'll get back to this for your case later.]

But instead of observing $\rho_{1:N}$ directly, you have the "indirect observations"
\begin{equation}
p(Y_{1:N}|\rho_{1:N}) = \prod_{i=1}^N p(Y_i|\rho_i) ,
\end{equation}
where (for notational convenience) I have written
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\rho_i) = L_i(\rho_i) . 
\end{equation}
In this case we can average the the predictive distribution according to the posterior distribution of latent variables:
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_{N+1}|Y_{1:N}) = \int p(\rho_{N+1}|\rho_{1:N})\,p(\rho_{1:N}|Y_{1:N})\,d\rho_{1:N} ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_{1:N}|Y_{1:N}) = \frac{p(Y_{1:N}|\rho_{1:N})\,p(\rho_{1:N})}{p(Y_{1:N})} .
\end{equation}

Although the preceding approach is conceptually straightforward, there is a more direct approach that is simpler to implement:
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_{N+1}|Y_{1:N}) = \int p(\rho_{N+1}|\theta)\,p(\theta|Y_{1:N})\,d\theta ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|Y_{1:N}) = \frac{p(Y_{1:N}|\theta)\,p(\theta)}{p(Y_{1:N})}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(Y_{1:N}|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N p(Y_i|\theta)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(Y_i|\theta) = \int p(Y_i|\rho_i)\,p(\rho_i|\theta)\,d\rho_i . 
\end{equation}
Along the way you would obtain the posterior distributions for each of the $N$ entities:
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_i|Y_{1:N}) = \int p(\rho_i|Y_i,\theta)\,p(\theta|Y_{1:N})\,d\theta,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_i|Y_i,\theta) = \frac{p(Y_i|\rho_i)\,p(\rho_i|\theta)}{p(Y_i|\theta)} . 
\end{equation}

As noted above, the main choices are the form of the prior for the parameter, $p(\rho_i|\theta)$, and the prior for the hyperparameter, $p(\theta)$. Here is one choice that is particularly well-suited to the unit interval. Let
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_i|\theta) = \sum_{j=1}^J \theta_j\,f_j(\rho_i) 
\end{equation}
where $\theta = (\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_J)$ is a vector of non-negative weights that sum to one and
\begin{equation}
f_j(\rho_i) = \textsf{Beta}(\rho_i|j,J-j+1) .
\end{equation}
This prior is a mixture of beta distributions; it is equivalent to a Bernstein polynomial restricted to be a density.
The larger $J$ is, the more flexible the prior can be.
This prior has the property that if $\theta_j = 1/J$ for all $j$ then $p(\rho_i|\theta) = \textsf{Uniform}(\rho_i|0,1)$.

Finally, let
\begin{equation}
p(\theta) = \textsf{Dirichlet}(\theta|\lambda) ,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_J)$. Note $E[\theta] = \lambda/\lambda_0$ where $\lambda_0 = \sum_{j=1}^J \lambda_j$. Also note that
\begin{equation}
p(\rho_i) = \int p(\rho_i|\theta)\,p(\theta)\,d\theta = \sum_{j=1}^J E[\theta_j]\,f_j(\rho_i) .
\end{equation}
If (for example) $\lambda_j = 1/J$ for all $j$, then $p(\rho_i) = \textsf{Uniform}(\rho_i|0,1)$.

A Gibbs sampler is straightforward to implement as long as
\begin{equation}
L_{ij} = \int p(Y_i|\rho_i)\,f_j(\rho_i)\,d\rho_i 
\end{equation}
is easy to compute for all $i$ and all $j$. It may be possible to integrate out nuisance parameters $\phi_i$ at this stage:
\begin{equation}
L_{ij} = \iint p(Y_i|\rho_i,\phi_i)\,f_j(\rho_i)\,p(\phi_i)\,d\phi_i\,d\rho_i . 
\end{equation}